# Why does eloquent JS want us to define the function "plus" ? I tried putting a nameless function in and it worked the same as far as i am aware

Tags: javascript

Regarding the below code-  Eloquent JS quotes:

> "It’s a bit silly that we have to define plus as a function, but operators in JavaScript, unlike functions, are not values, so you can’t pass them as arguments."

```
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) {return a + b;}
  return array.reduce(plus)/ array.length;    
}

function age(p) { return p.died - p.born; }
function male(p) { return p.sex == "m"; }
function female(p) { return p.sex == "f"; }

console.log(average(ancestry.filter(male).map(age)));
// → 61.67
console.log(average(ancestry.filter(female).map(age)));
// → 54.56
```

This is the code that i prefer and it seemed to work, so what exactly is he trying to say?

```
function average(array) {

  return array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; })/ array.length;    
}
```

Comment: There's no difference between your code and the code in the book. The point of the comment is that the `+` operator is not a *function* and cannot be used as such. That is, you cannot write just `return array.reduce(+);` which you could do in a Lisp-like language.

Comment: I think what the comment is saying is that you can't do something like:
`return array.reduce( a + b )`, but rather have to pass in a function. It isn't saying anything about unnamed functions. But for someone learning js, it's a lot more clear if you pass a named function as a variable to show what exactly what that function should accomplish.

Comment: ES6 is even better with fat arrow... `const average = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / array.length`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the same thing the book is doing, you're just not giving the function a name and making it reusable.

What the book is saying is that it would be nice to just do this:

```
function average(array) {
  return array.reduce(+) / array.length;    
  // Can't do this ---^
}
```

We can't, we have to pass a function. In the book, he's passing `plus`. In your example, you're passing an anonymous function. But it still passing a  function wrapped around an operator either way.

There has been [some discussion](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/a-twist-on-functional-operatorsr) of allowing some kind of operator reference:

```
// DOESN'T EXIST (yet?)
function average(array) {
  return array.reduce({{+}}) / array.length;    
  //                  ^^^^^---- placeholder for functional operator syntax,
  //                            this is not actual proposed syntax
}
```

There doesn't seem to be much appetite for it, though, esp. in light of concise arrow functions:

```
function average(array) {
  return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;    
}
```